# In what real-world scenarios is a semantic database better than a relational one?

Tags: algorithm, database-design, computer-science, semantic-web, semantic-markup

Are there any real live (non-academic) and public (open-source or free) examples of a semantic database like Metalog being used to solve a computing problem that traditionally had been done with relational databases?

Comment: What makes you think that relational database are, in any way, "not semantic" ?

Comment: consider asking on answers.semanticweb.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantic databases work much better if only part of your data follows a schema.

If you need additional columns in a semantic database, you just add them. Even for single rows. This is hard or inefficient in a relational database.

Also clustering is much more simple with semantic or tuple databases. Most often, this means just to install the database on N servers and set a few config options.

Comment: Lawks!  Where are the "semantics" then in a semantic database if you can just add stuff willy nilly?

Comment: The semantics are that a column isn't just a name but a type. So you don't add NAME to a PERSON table but, say, `http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/contact#fullName` which means "The data value is the full name of a real, living person" and if you encounter a similar field in another table *or even a different database*, you don't have to guess what it means. Instead, you will **know**.

Comment: In relational databases too, a column is always of a well-defined type.

Comment: Erwin: Then you didn't understand my comment. `VARCHAR` is a data type. It doesn't **mean** anything.

Comment: I understand your comment all too well.  Let me debunk.  You wrote : "the semantics are that a column isn't just a name but a type".  To me, this clearly suggests that you are convinced that in a relational database, a column is indeed nothing more than just a name, and not a type.  Well, you are wrong.  In a relational database, a column is a name PLUS a type.  How the _APPEARANCE_ of a value in a column contributes to the meaning of the row in which it appears, is defined by the table's "external predicate", which states the intended interpretation of the (rows in) the table.

Comment: Now I have a "semantic" database, in which I add, along the lines of your comment, "http://www.erwinsmout.be/project#dscr", and also "http://www.erwinsmout.be/foo#bar".  You claim that it is possible to tell what that means.  Please explain, because I can't.

Comment: Simple: If you have two tables with `VARCHAR NAME(32)` that doesn't tell you if that's the same name or whether there is any kind of relation between the two columns or not. If the columns have a RDF tag, if the tag is the same, then it's the same kind of data.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: I don't think you follow Erwin's point.  'VARCHAR' is the *data* type, 'FullName' (i.e., the column name) is the *semantic type*, if you will.  The data type is purely concerned with the representation, not the meaning.

Comment: Semantic databases can also accommodate data from multiple schemas, on-the-fly, which is perhaps more compelling than their ability to handle schema-less data (which, while useful, isn't very semantic). Note that it is also possible to extend schemas easily on-the-fly (e.g. by creating a subclass or subproperty).